# Chapter name followed by section name in the left side of the header of all pages

Tags: header-footer

In fancy-header mode I want to put at the left of the upper head of each page, the name of the current chapter followed, after a separator sign, by the name of the current section.
How can I manage to do that, taking into account that my chapters and sections are addchapter and addsection (they have no numero but appear in the table of content).

Comment: What do you mean by "addchapter" and "addsection"? What `\documentclass` are you using? Are you using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) (or what do you mean by "fancy-header mode")? What should be the display on the first page of a chapter? ...surely not that same as elsewhere. What happens to the second page of a chapter where there is no first section yet?

Comment: I use the commands \addchap {name of the chapter} and \addsec {name of the section} to start new chapter and new section. 
I use the  documentclass[12pt,oneside,american,english,french{scrbook}
I have also:
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

When there is only the table of of content of the document , I want to see "Table of Content"

Comment: When there is only the table of of content of the document , I want to see "Table of Content" at the left of the header.
When I am in a Chapter and not in a section , I want to see the name of the chapter.
When I am in a section, I want to see the name of the chapter followed by the name of the section at the left of the header.

Comment: And what do you want to see on the first page of a chapter where you presumably have the chapter title within the page?

Comment: Yes, on the first page of a chapter there is its title together with the beginning of its text (no page breakdown). If there is already on this page a section, I want the names of the chapter and of the first section occuring on this page  in the header of this first page. If there is no section yet, the name of the chapter alone will be sufficient.

Comment: Usage of `fancyhdr` together with a KOMA-class is not recommended. The new and modern `scrlayer-scrpage` will be more suited for the job. With a little more information, best in form of a minimal working example, we sure will be able to find a solution.

Comment: We'll need more detail here to help.